# I am unsure how to fix: 'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str '

Tags: python

```
new_url = sync_url+'/'+uri+'/data'
```

I tried `new_url = sync_url+'/'+uri+'/str(data)'`  but I keep getting the same error. I am confused which one is the int. I thought it was data but I keep getting a error code.

Comment: Either `sync_url` or `uri` are `int` type

Comment: Can you provide more details about what the variables `sync_url` & `uri` are?

Comment: What's the output of `type(uri)` and `type(sync_url)`?

Comment: `'/data'`, quoted as it is, is a string, not a reference to a variable called `data`. If you do `'/str(data)'`, you only will get a string that is literally "/str(data)".

Comment: To create strings referencing many variables, consider using formatted strings instead of concatenating `str()` calls to each variable, something like `f'{sync_url}/{uri}/{data}'`. There are [many different ways](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=string+formatting+python) of doing it.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I am understanding better on how to debug my errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `sync_url` or `uri` are of `int` type.

To solve your issue, check the type of these variables, and for the int one, you will need to wrap it with `str()`

For example, if `uri` is of type `int`, the following solves the problem:

```py
new_url = sync_url + '/' + str(uri) + '/data'
```